# Python Thread Module

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to test this simple code I found in Pydev using the thread module because the threading module is not an option for me. The threads don't even run and all it does is print HELLO and exits the program. I was using this module with my original program but it was doing the same thing so I thought I'd start with the simple test of the source. Why is this happening?

Code:

```
import thread
import time

# Define a function for the thread
def print_time( threadName, delay):
   count = 0
   while count < 5:
      time.sleep(delay)
      count += 1
      print "%s: %s" % ( threadName, time.ctime(time.time()) )

# Create two threads as follows
try:
   thread.start_new_thread( print_time, ("Thread-1", 2, ) )
   thread.start_new_thread( print_time, ("Thread-2", 4, ) )
except:
   print "Error: unable to start thread"

print "HELLO"
```

It does not even produce any errors or exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your main thread is ending before you can see the output for either of the threads, just put a delay on the main thread at the end:

```
print "HELLO"
time.sleep(20)
```

If you were using the `threading` module you could also use the threads `.join()` method to wait for it to finish but I'm not sure the equivalent in the `thread` module.